# How important is it to get your dog vaccinated for heartworm in India?

Tags: dogs, vaccination

Is heartworm common among dogs in India, and is it necessary to get dogs vaccinated against it?

Answer (score 6):

The only way dogs get heartworm is through an infected mosquito and India has a ***lot*** of mosquitos and you cannot tell if a mosquito is an infected carrier, same problem with mosquitos and dengue fever. So, as a general statement, the risk of heartworm would be quite high and the best way to deal with heartworm is to stop it before it happens, so vaccination would be a very good idea because curing after the fact is quite hard (and much more expensive).

Comment: It's important for a dog to be on heartworm preventative like Sentinel or Trifexis year-round regardless of where you live, but even more important in areas with lots of mosquitos. There is currently no vaccine (like there is for rabies) according to the [American Heartworm Society](https://www.heartwormsociety.org/pet-owner-resources/heartworm-basics#is-there-a-vaccine-for-heartworm-disease), but there are a variety of prevention methods.